# Smoothing luminous intensity map plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a bird´s eye view of a luminous intesity pattern image I extract using some simulation software, unfortunately I cant extract the data just the image, it looks something like this:

[image: Original beam pattern]

and I need to make it look something like this instead

[image: What I want]

Since I don´t have access to the source data I was wondering if I could do some image processing, I should note it is possible to segment each color using the segmentation toolbox.

I am just looking for some ideas,

Thanks

Comment: Any processing on the plotted data means lost information and accumulation of errors due to rendering. It is just bad science, you shoudl try to reproduce or obtain the data, not fake plots

Comment: I understand that, but this is just for my visualization purposes, will not use this for anything other than a test.